# How to get logs and it's data having word "error" in then and how to configure logstashPipeLine.conf file for the same?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Currently I am working on an application where I need to create documents from particular data from a file at specific location. I have set up logstash pipeline configuration.

Here is what it looks like currently:

```
input{
file{
path => "D:\ELK_Info\logstashInput.log"
start_position => "beginning"
}
}
#Possible IF condition here in the filter

output {
 #Possible IF condition here
  http {
    url => "http://localhost:9200/<index_name>/<type_name>"
    http_method => "post"
    format => "json"
  }
}
```

I want to provide IF condition in output before calling API.
The condition should be like, **"If data from input contains word 'Error', only then proceed further to call http API mentioned."**

Any idea on how may I do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Please look at this link: [Ignore and move to next pattern if log contains a specific word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50322771/ignore-and-move-to-next-pattern-if-log-contains-a-specific-word)

The first step is to look whehther input has error as key word, if so, continue the parsing by second grok. If no, just forget the input.